# Logging inside a Linq fluent chain

Tags: c#, linq

I've posted this to Stack Overflow, but someone voted to close as they felt it was opinion based, so I'm bringing it over to Code Review.

I have some Linq fluent chains to shape an original IEnumerable of objects into the proper form.

During this process, I'd like to capture and log the reason why some objects are "rejected" in a `Where` clause.

I was thinking about something similar to this (reduced use-case, just for the sake of demonstration):

```
var bar = SomeEnumerable
    .SelectMany(...)
    .Where(i =>
    {
        if(...)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Log "failure" to in-memory list
            return false;
        }
    })
    .ToDictionary(...);
```

I understand that this introduces some side-effect, though minimal, but if at all possible, I would like to eliminate it.

Does this match some "pattern" that can be expressed in the context of Linq chains?

Thanks

Comment: I try as hard as I can do not have side effects inside a linq statement. If I need side effects I switch it to a foreach statement with s yield.  but if you really want to do side effects in a linq-y way then I would suggest mimicking the Do operator of Observerables.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about that, but the `Where` clause will only let through the objects that match, so I'd have no way of catching those that don't match. We'd need like a "tee" operator. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Personally, logging is one of the side effects I can be okay with. If you aren't already, I would just recommend that you make the side effect explicit by putting it inside of a named method. Perhaps something like `.Where(FilterAndLogRejectionReasons)`, with a `private bool FilterAndLogRejectionReasons(YourType item)` defined with an explanatory doc comment later in the class.

Comment: Why does this question have so many upvotes? It should be closed for the servere lack of context.

Comment: @t3chb0t maybe it was upvoted because other people considered it contained all the necessary context to understand the concept. I'm all for learning how to properly post on this site. Instead of losing it, you could have simply pointed me in the right direction, and used you VTC rights, which you did. Now, if you could explain what additional context would help you better understand the question, maybe I can provide it, but I think the example, being reduced to its simpler use-case, says what it has to say. You certainly don't expect me to post 200 lines of code, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it seems to cloud up your code a bit. You could write your own LINQ-style extension method similar to the ones below. It uses a couple of C#7 features (tuple types and local methods). The first just recreates the collection with the results associated with each item (to avoid any side-effects of possibly calling the predicate multiple times) and the second will iterate and log/filter as your lambda does.

```
namespace System.Linq
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public static class Enumerable
    {
        public static IEnumerable<(TSource, bool)> WhereResult<TSource>(
            this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            }

            if (predicate == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
            }

            return _();

            IEnumerable<(TSource, bool)> _()
            {
                foreach (TSource current in source)
                {
                    yield return (current, predicate(current));
                }
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<(TSource, bool)> LogWhere<TSource>(
            this IEnumerable<(TSource, bool)> source)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            }

            return _();

            IEnumerable<(TSource, bool)> _()
            {
                foreach ((TSource, bool) current in source)
                {
                    if (current.Item2)
                    {
                        yield return current;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log(...);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a first thought off the top of my head. Could be improved easily with some AOP instead of the explicit logging call, for instance.

Comment: Why do you wrap the yields in the local methods `_();`?

Comment: @HenrikHansen it allows the parameter check part of the method to be evaluated immediately and the yield part to be evaluated lazily. If they weren't in local methods, the parameter check part would be executed lazily as well and that often results in unexpected exception timing.